# Finding a basis for a subspace in $\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find a basis for the space and determine its dimension.

The space of all matrices $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a& b\\c& d\end{pmatrix}$$ in $\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ such that $a + d = 0$ (in other words, the [sum of the] diagonal = 0).

I'm not sure how to even begin this question.  Please help!

Comment: Do you know what "basis" means? Can you write down *any* matrices in the given space? Can you write down any matrices *not* in the given space? Can you guess the dimension of the space?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\
c&-a\end{matrix}\right)=a\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\
0&-1\end{matrix}\right)+b\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\
0&0\end{matrix}\right)+c\left(\begin{matrix}0&0\\
1&0\end{matrix}\right)=aJ+bK+cL$$
and verify that the matrices $J,K$ and $L$ are linearly independant.

Answer (score 1):

Note that that $b,c$ are free. Note that $a+d=0\iff -a=d$, so you want $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a& b\\c& -a\end{pmatrix}$$

Can you move on?

**Hint**

$$A=a\begin{pmatrix}1& 0\\0& -1\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}0& 0\\1& 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Therefore the basis is given by those 3 linearly independent matrices and the dimension is 3.  Thanks!

Comment: @NicholasJelsma Wasn't that hard, was it? Maybe next time you can try a little more by yourself before asking.

Comment: @NicholasJelsma (Of course, the above should be read in a friendly tone) =)

Comment: @NicholasJelsma If you find this answer helpful you can upvote it or even accept it.